# ScrollViewer Items Preventing Scrolling

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, desktop-application, scrollviewer

As should be evident from the code below, I have a ScrollViewer whose only two children are two TreeViews. Each TreeView consists of one TreeViewItem, which itself contains a ListBox. The ListBox's items are dynamically generated. It's quite convoluted, but I haven't thought of anything better yet, so there it is. The issue that I am having is getting the entire thing to scroll as one control. Here's the XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer MaxHeight="600" MinHeight="40">
    <TreeView Name="TVControl">
        <TreeViewItem Name="TVI1" Header="TreeViewItem1">
            <ListBox Name="ListBox1" />
                <!-- List of dynamically populated items -->
        </TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Name="TVI2" Header="TreeViewItem2">
            <ListBox Name="ListBox2" />
                <!-- List of dynamically populated items -->
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

If my mouse is over the vertical scroll bar, the mouse wheel works, but it doesn't work when the mouse is over the rest of the control. It seems to me that I would be able to traverse up the tree from within an event to control the scrolling, but I am at a loss for what that might be. Also, if there's a simpler way to achieve the exact same result visually than having to go 5 controls deep, I am open to that suggestion as well!

Comment: I would guess because the other controls are marking the MouseWheel event as handled, effectively "swallowing" the event and preventing your ScrollViewer from scrolling. This is because ListBox contains a ScrollViewer in its default control template.

Try setting ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll to "False" on your ListBoxes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @David Meredith, but it didn't fix the issue. I even tried setting the TreeView's ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll to False, as well, but to no avail. You have, however, given me another lead, so I'm going to do some research on seeing if I can manually keep that event from being "swallowed" so it can continue up the tree to my ScrollViewer. So thanks for that! I'll post back if it works.

Comment: You could also use a tool like Snoop or WPF Inspector to confirm what it is that's actually handling the MouseWheel event. Good luck!